# openOptionsMenu() will not work in appcompat-v7 22.1.0 or newer

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-optionsmenu, options-menu

I've seen several reports of issues where *openOptionsMenu()* will not work on various Android versions, eg:

[openOptionsMenu() across android versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764854/openoptionsmenu-across-android-versions)

[openOptionsMenu() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196923/openoptionsmenu-not-working)

but the issue I have seems to be related to the version of the appcompat-v7 support library being used.

In essence, with the newer versions of appcompat-v7 the menu will appear fine when *openOptionsMenu()* is called if your activity extends *Activity* but will not work if you extend *ActionBarActivity* or *AppCompatActivity* (ie use the compatibility library). In older versions of appcompat-v7 it works fine.

It is reproducible, as follows:

1. In Android Studio, Import Sample 'ActionBarCompat-Basic'
2. Add a button to the screen, which invokes *openOptionsMenu()*
3. Note that this works fine, as the old version of the library, appcompat-v7:21.0.3 is used in the sample
4. Change the dependency to use appcompat-v7:23.0.1, rebuild, and when clicking on the button the menu will *not* appear.
5. Change the main activity to extend Activity (ie no app compatability) - it works
6. Change the main activity to extend AppCompatActivity (ie using app compatibility libarry) - it fails

After some testing, I've found that this stopped working in appcompat-v7:22.1.0, and will no longer work in any newer version of this jar.

This behaviour is identical on the emulator and on a physical device, and on Android versions 5.1.1(23) and 2.1(7) which were the two versions I tested it with.

I've added a comment to this bug: [Android issue tracker bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185217)

Any suggestions, ideas or workarounds appreciated!

-Steve

Comment: I am experiencing the same bug :(

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have actually found a workaround for this. It involves overriding the `openOptionsMenu()` method:

```
@Override
public void openOptionsMenu()
{
    mActionBar.showOverflowMenu();
}
```

In order for `showOverflowMenu()` to work on devices with a physical menu key that are below API 19, use this: [How to force action bar overflow icon to show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show)

`mActionBar` is assigned as such:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mActionBar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) getActionBar(getWindow().getDecorView())
```

This is the `getActionBar()` method:

```
public static ViewGroup getActionBar(View view)
{
    try
    {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

            if (viewGroup instanceof android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)
            {
                return viewGroup;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                ViewGroup actionBar = getActionBar(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));

                if (actionBar != null)
                {
                    return actionBar;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Calling `openOptionsMenu()` from an AppCompatActivity now works!

**NOTE:** I tested this on API 26, but seeing as the `getActionBar()` method works far below that, I see no reason the rest of this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

More simple than The Wanderer's post and it goes fine in genymotion and also in my cell phone (marshmallow):

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

//btMainMenu is a button
public void btMainMenu_click(View view) {
    final View view2 = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
    if (view2 instanceof Toolbar) {
        ((Toolbar) view2).showOverflowMenu();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("What a pity!, it doesn't work..., view2 is not toolbar");
    }
}
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37060139