# Android openOptionsMenu does nothing in KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-optionsmenu

I have a button with `openOptionsMenu()` method from Activity in it, it works fine on other Android versions, but on KitKat it does absolutely nothing... Why is that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996333

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently you have to override this method from Activity and write some additional code in it, so here is what I did, thanks to the comment of [Luis A. Florit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1483390/luis-a-florit) from this question [How to open the options menu programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133318/how-to-open-the-options-menu-programmatically)

```
@Override
public void openOptionsMenu() {
    super.openOptionsMenu();
    Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if ((config.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) > Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        int originalScreenLayout = config.screenLayout;
        config.screenLayout = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
        super.openOptionsMenu();
        config.screenLayout = originalScreenLayout;
    } else {
        super.openOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with the Nexus 10 API 27 emulator.  It worked in the other emulators.  This solved my problem.  Thank you for sharing.