# Menu is not displaying on activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-menu, android-inflate

I am trying to add a Menu to my `activity_main.xml`. I added `menu.xml` to the `res/menu` directory and inflated it to `activity_main.xml`.

The problem is it is not showing. Do I need something to trigger the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method?

[image: Screenshot]

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/toast"
        android:title="Raise Toast"
        />
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   package com.nejat.lunchlist;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    String[] autoAddr  = {"mall", "foodcourt","school","places"};
    ArrayList<Restaurant> model = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    RestaurantAdapter adapter = null;
    AutoCompleteTextView addr;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = null;
    ListView listView;
    private AutoCompleteTextView name = null;
    private AutoCompleteTextView address= null;
    private RadioGroup rButton;
    TabHost tabHost;
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    EditText  datePickerEditText;
    Restaurant r = new Restaurant();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        datePickerEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        datePickerEditText.setOnClickListener(datePicker);
        btn.setOnClickListener(onSave);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restaurants);
        adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(model,getApplicationContext());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(selectItem);
        addr = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.addr);
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,autoAddr);
        addr.setThreshold(1);
        addr.setAdapter(adapter2);

        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        TabHost.TabSpec tabspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("List");
        tabspec.setContent(R.id.restaurants);
        tabspec.setIndicator("Restaurants");
        tabHost.addTab(tabspec);

        tabspec = getTabHost().newTabSpec("Details");
        tabspec.setContent(R.id.details);
        tabspec.setIndicator("Details");
        tabHost.addTab(tabspec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }
    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener datePicker = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int mminnute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog time = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    datePickerEditText.setText(hourOfDay + "/"+ minute);
                    r.setDate(hourOfDay + "/"+ minute);
                }
            },mHour,mminnute,false);
            time.show();

        }

    };


    private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AutoCompleteTextView  name = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
            RadioGroup rb = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.types);
            r.setAddress(addr.getText().toString());
            r.setName(name.getText().toString());
            r.setNote(note.getText().toString());
            switch (rb.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
                case R.id.sit_down:
                    r.setType("Sit_Down");
                    break;
                case R.id.take_out:
                    r.setType("Take_Out");
                    break;
                case R.id.delivery:
                    r.setType("Delivery");
                    break;
            }


            adapter.add(r);


        }
    };
                private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener selectItem = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Restaurant r= model.get(position);

                        name = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                        address = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.addr);
                        EditText note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);


                        rButton = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.types);
                        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
                        note.setText(r.getNote().toString());
                        name.setText(r.getName().toString());
                        address.setText(r.getAddress().toString());
                        if(r.getType().equals("Sit_Down")){
                            rButton.check(R.id.sit_down);

                        }
                        else if(r.getType().equals(("Delivery"))){
                            rButton.check((R.id.details));
                        }
                        else if(r.getType().equals("Take_Out")){
                            rButton.check(R.id.take_out);

                        }



                    }
                };

}
```

ativity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/restaurants"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:stretchColumns="1">

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="Name:" />

                    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/name" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="Address:" />

                    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/addr" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="Date:" />

                    <EditText android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:editable="false"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="Type:" />

                    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/types">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/take_out"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Take-Out" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/sit_down"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Sit-Down" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/delivery"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Delivery" />
                    </RadioGroup>

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>

                    <TextView android:text="Note:" />

                    <EditText android:id="@+id/note"/>
                </TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Save" />
            </TableLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Log

```
12-07 03:56:24.774 1640-1665/system_process D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
12-07 03:56:29.761 2885-2890/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
12-07 03:56:29.764 2885-2890/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
12-07 03:56:30.059 2885-2890/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

Comment: You do not have an ActionBar, from what I can see. Force set an ActionBar or if the device has a hardware Menu button, press it to show the menu

Comment: I just have added the ActionBar to  be showed `always` but  it is not working. even the log is not showing. @CoolGuyCG

Comment: You can use AndroidStudio New/Activity/Gallery... option to add a default templated activity, some of them come with a complete ActionBar and Menu configuration. So you'll be able to compare with your work.

Comment: I fixed this bug by this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996333/openoptionsmenu-function-not-working-in-ics/17903128#17903128).

Comment: @Nejweti, can you post the full Activity code here?

Comment: @CoolGuyCG I updated the question.

Comment: Can I get a screenshot of how it looks on a device? What I have written here is drastically different from what you are doing.

Comment: I added the screeshot @CoolGuyCG

Comment: What are your expectations for the menu? If you want it to show at the top then I'm pretty sure you need an `ActionBar`.

Comment: please provide the activity_main.xml code.

Comment: I am following a project from Busy coder's Guide for Android and I want the menu to be at the bottom and The items horizontally. @DigitalNinja

Comment: the reason for The menu not displaying at the top is because I am not extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: If AppCompatActivity solved it for you then write it as the accepted answer, people may add later findings to it. And sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the menu not displaying at the top is because I am extending TabActivity instead of AppCompatActivity.