# openOptionsMenu does not work: wrong SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I use `openOptionsMenu()` to open the menu in applications with special GUI - for example, apps that only show graphics (fullscreen apps without toolbars etc.), upon a long press of the screen.

I can see that I made it work in the past on other applications, and I suppose that it was by using in the Manifest,

```
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

I am now unable to make this work (the code would be):

```
    myButton.setOnLongClickListener(
            new OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    openOptionsMenu();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            );
```

I think that Android Studio is using the wrong SDK. In fact,

- the values I put in the Manifest ("min" and "target" set to 15) are overridden;
- the values used should be those of build.gradle - and again, I set "compile", "min" and "target" set to 15, but I do not see the app
  working properly and I think the SDK selection may not be happening;
- as I check the produced APK the Manifest entries for the SDK (minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion) are missing.

The *build.gradle* file according to the Android Studio interface shows:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 15
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId '[...AppID...]'
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 15
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }
```

As written above, the AndroidManifest.xml in the compiled APK (after `apktool -d`) does not mention any SDK selection.

I expect that the app compiled for SDK 15 would open the (very required) menu upon call of `openOptionsMenu()`. What the compiled app does now, upon debugging, is to go instead in the method that would /close/ the menu (clearly a satanic intention).

**EDIT:** the information about the specific case of Google butchering `openOptionsMenu()` after some SDK version is at 
[openOptionsMenu function not working in ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996333/openoptionsmenu-function-not-working-in-ics)

Comment: try returning true from the longclick method

Comment: @Vivek Mishra: bur that 'return false;' occurs _after_ the openOptionsMenu() call, which already sends you (through breakpoint and step-in) first to some unrecognized bytecode, and immediately after to the Window.closePanel() method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I have made a mistake. 
I realized that my past, working code did not just compile for SDK 15, it also contained an *override* as follows, and as suggested by user *tallicalord* in the previously linked page:

```
@Override public void openOptionsMenu() {
    Configuration cfg = getResources().getConfiguration();
    if( (cfg.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)>Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE){
        int shelf = cfg.screenLayout;
        cfg.screenLayout = Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
        super.openOptionsMenu();
        cfg.screenLayout = shelf;
    }else{
        super.openOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

So it is possible that the SDK selection, even though more mysterious in Android-Gradle (which removes references in the Manifest), was not the problem.

I shall note that it is very unfortunate how Google manages to make people waste uncountable hours for problems that did not need to exist at all.